Unable to scroll when using Flutter web as an iframe
I am having an issue where I have a web app served to customers as an iframe solution.
I am having trouble scrolling on mobile browsers and the closest solution is removing touch-action: none from the generated style properties or setting it to auto at least.
Now, I have tried many things but I am not able to override the touch-action style attribute.
Following is my setup:
flutter doctor -v output

The actual generated code I could see in the browser element view. Changing touch-action to auto helps but I need a permanent solution at the time of build.

